# How to get latest commit from a repository in IntelliJ using GitHub Api-Kohsuke?

Tags: java, github, intellij-idea, commit

I am kinda new in the Java world and I was wondering how can I get the latest commit of a Repo that I do not own.
For example I want to take only the last commit from the VsVim repository.

I tried looking into some solutions using GitHubBuilder :

gitHubConnection.getRepository(url).listCommits().toList().get(0).getCommitDate()

For example I want to extract the commit date and massage. This works, however it is extremely slow(does not even load for couple of minutes and I just stop the programm) when we talk about big repositories with lots of commits like the above mentioned example VsVim.

The second attempt was to try use the

```
GHCommitQueryBuilder
```

GHCommitQueryBuilder queryBuilder = gitHubConnection.getRepository(url).queryCommits().since(since).until(until);

```
GHCommit latestCommit = queryBuilder.list().toList().get(0);
latestCommit.getCommitDate();
```

Here I have to define with a Date variable the "since" and "until". For example if I define a 1-month range for the VsVim repository it will load for about 10-12 seconds which is fair enough. However, I do not want to hardcode such time range since it throws an error if the requested repo does not have a commit in this range. For example if the repo does not have a commit for 3 months and I hard code "since" and "until" it will break my programm.

The solution I came up with would be to accept Date input from the user so that I can use it when building this GHCommitQueryBuilder.

I also saw a method called "getCommit(String sha1) which accepts the Sha of the last commit. Maybe if I can somehow automate the process of retrieving the Sha1 I can use this method :)

Please let me know if there is a way.

Thanks for the help guys. Appreciate all the answers!